# Flutter app crashes on start using fire base?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Started a new flutter project and trying to use firestore.

After following all step to add project to fire base.

Adding all plugins to pubspec.yaml and then running the project.

The log cat shows this:

```
04-04 14:54:56.061 24084-24084/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firestoreflutterchat, PID: 24084
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4869)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4461)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4401)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.firestoreflutterchat-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4854)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4461) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4401) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1270) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method
```

Before adding cloud firestore plugin the newly project was running after adding this i am having issue.

This is the Pubspec.yaml file :

```
 version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+3
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter




flutter:


  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: did you setup everything correctly? in firebase and in your project? rebuild is needed..flutter hot start and hot restart does'nt work

Comment: yes did it as fire base recommended but cloud firestore plugin i think is creating problem.

Comment: add your pubspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem did not resolve with multidex , only way was to remove it and follow this link

[resolve multidex issue](https://medium.com/@olawale_alabi/android-flutter-64k-methods-dex-limit-how-to-use-proguard-in-development-728af11a4e22)

it worked by removing these in your gradle

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and changing from this

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

to this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
    }
    debug{
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and in your path: /android/app

right click and create a file named `proguard-rules.pro`

and put these files inside the file

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems some setups are still remaining for Firebase.
Checkout this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#setup) and set up the .json and .plist file accordingly in project.
If you further still facing the issue,
I would recommend some steps.
1) Delete all the build files of the project, invalid cache and restart android studio.
2) Follow the below changes in your project.
**build.gradle file**

```
android {
.....
defaultConfig {
......
 multiDexEnabled true//add this line
}
......
dependencies{
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'//add this line
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
....
<application
....
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" 
...>
 <activity   />
...

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"  gives error as it is unresolved

Comment: bypass this line and check again.

Comment: what do you mean by by pass line

Comment: Also the error in logs after trying to add multidex is :                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firestoreflutterchat/com.example.firestoreflutterchat.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.firestoreflutterchat.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity